# PubNub - Messages are received both as Push and as realtime [Android]

Tags: android, pubnub

I subscribe to all necessary channels in 2 places:

```java
// For receiving real time (regular) messages
pubnub.subscribe().channels(channels).execute();
```

and for Push

```java
pubnub.addPushNotificationsOnChannels()
                            .pushType(PNPushType.FCM)
                            .channels(channels)
                            .deviceId(firebaseMessageingTokenForThisUser)
```

When I send messages I specify data for Push as well:

```java
PushPayloadHelper pushPayloadHelper = new PushPayloadHelper();

// set FCM payload
pushPayloadHelper.setFcmPayload(fcmPayload);

// Set APNs payload
pushPayloadHelper.setApnsPayload(apnsPayload);

// Common payload for realtime PubNub subscribe
Map<String, Object> commonPayload = new HashMap<>();
commonPayload.put("message", jsonPayload);
pushPayloadHelper.setCommonPayload(commonPayload);

pubnub.publish()
                .channel(channelName)
                .message(pushPayloadHelper.build())...
```

**Expected behaviour:**

1. When Android client is in foreground messages are delivered as real time
2. When app was closed/killed messages are delivered as Push

**Current behavior:**

When app is running, messages are delivered both as Push (Firebase Push service method is invoked)

and real time (`public void message(@NotNull PubNub pubnub, @NotNull PNMessageResult message)` method is invoked)

What do I do wrong? Couldn't find anything about it in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PubNub Realtime Messaging & Mobile Push Notifications

> subscribe to all necessary channels in 2 places

First, just to keep terminology in order, you ***subscribe*** to channels for *realtime* messages and you ***register devices*** on channels for ***mobile push notifications***. Subscribe only applies to realtime messages. It's a nitpick but important to keep things clear when we talk about this.

And yes, every time you publish a message that includes a mobile push payload, it gets delivered to active *subscribers* to the channel and delivered as a *mobile push notification* to devices that are registered for push on that channel. This is expected and necessary.

The trick is that when the app is in the foreground (active), you simply just don't display the push notification, because you received it in the `addListener''s` message` handler.

So the question is, what does your "mobile push message receiver" handler look like?

Here's a [really old blog/video that explains all this](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/mobile-push-notifications-101-apns-gcm-vs-pubsub-explained/). While it is over 5 years old, it is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear with terminology now. I just expected different behaviour from PubNub. I used to think that PubNub would try to deliver message via Push channel only if message delivery via subscribe channel was not available right now (app was killed). **So only one delivery method at a time.**
In the 5 year old article there are the following lines: `For example, if you were to register on an APNS channel on Apple’s network, but if we also subscribe to a PubNub channel, we’ll receive the data on both of the networks depending on the state of the application`

Comment: I need one simple thing - I want messages to be delivered no matter what state the application is in. This is why I will always include push payload. My question - is there any way to make PubNub use only 1 method at a time? E.g. when app is active/alive - then only via subscribe channel.

Comment: No not really. Due to limitations of TCP/HTTP, you can't know for sure if a device is actually connected or not at any given instance. That is why there is something called `presenceTimeout`. If a device's network drops or the device just leaves abruptly, then there is not guaranteed way to know that they actually left at that moment. In some scenarios, yes, you can know it left but just not every scenario. Therefore you can't do an `if connected, send via realtime, else send via push notification` type optimization. If you could, we would.

Comment: Furthermore, why is receiving the push notification "no matter what" an issue. We have mega-size customers using this with no issues. Again, just ignore push notification when the app is active/subscribed.